# Variable framerate lossless video from yuv422 images

Tags: command-line, video, ffmpeg, framerate, lossless

I've been pulling my hair lately with FFmpeg commandline. Be aware that I am not an FFmpeg expert. Here is my problem:

I have a bunch of YUV422 images as such:

```
image0.yuv
image1.yuv
..
image450.yuv
```

Along with these I have a file containing timestamps for every image, say:

```
timestamps.txt
```

I would like to encode a lossless video (maybe with `-c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv422p`) from these with every image displayed at its correct timstamp. Here are the things I tried in vain:

- use `-f concat` and provide a file containing a list like this:

  ```
  file 'image0.yuv'
  duration '0.0515'
  file 'image0.yuv'
  duration '0.0721'
  ... etc
  ```

  this solution does not work because I need to provide a frame size (which is not included in the raw yuv files)
- something like `cat *.yuv | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 800x600 -pix_fmt yuv422p -framerate 0.5 -i - -c:v libx264 -pix_fmt yuv422p out.mp4` which doesn't work neither because I can't provide it timestamps for each image (variable framerate) but just use the fixed `-framerate` argument
- I'm aware of the `-vsync vfr` argument but can't manage to make it work properly

I would be eternally grateful for any piece of advice, thanks :)

Comment: See https://video.stackexchange.com/a/19726

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to specify common input options for the concat demuxer. Quick and dirty workaround: convert all YUV images to something that can be read without having to specify further options. For example:

```
for f in *.yuv; do ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 320x240 -pix_fmt yuv422p -i "$f" "${f%%.yuv}.avi"; done
```

Then, construct your concat file with the AVI files instead.

Or, with GNU `parallel`:

```
parallel 'ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 320x240 -pix_fmt yuv422p -i {} {.}.avi' ::: *.yuv
```

Or use [the method linked to in the comments](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/19723/how-to-embed-multiple-images-in-a-video-recording/19726#19726) wherein you can pipe the YUV images and later modify the CFR timestamps of the generated file to become VFR.